# How to install the Android emulator skins folder via the command line?

Tags: android, python, emulation

I am automating the Android SDK installation via a Python script and I can't figure out where the skins folder is coming from.

It seems the folder is being created, inside the SDK location, when an emulator is created via AVD Manager UI (when it is launched from Android Studio):

```sh
ll ~/Library/android/sdk
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  17 user  staff   544 Aug 14 20:33 ./
drwxr-xr-x   6 user  staff   192 Dec  7  2017 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff    16 Aug 14 19:35 .knownPackages
drwxr-xr-x   7 user  staff   224 Jul 17 14:56 build-tools/
drwxr-xr-x  51 user  staff  1632 Jan 11  2018 docs/
drwxr-xr-x  18 user  staff   576 Jul 22 01:26 emulator/
drwxr-xr-x   6 user  staff   192 Oct  9  2017 extras/
drwxr-xr-x   3 user  staff    96 Jan  2  2018 fonts/ # <- Where is it coming from?
drwxr-xr-x   8 user  staff   256 Jul 25 18:28 licenses/
drwxr-xr-x   3 user  staff    96 Oct  9  2017 patcher/
drwxr-xr-x  19 user  staff   608 Jun  6 17:30 platform-tools/
drwxr-xr-x   9 user  staff   288 Aug 12 19:55 platforms/
drwxr-xr-x  26 user  staff   832 Apr 25 10:53 skins/ # <- Where is it coming from?
drwxr-xr-x   8 user  staff   256 Jan 11  2018 sources/
drwxr-xr-x   8 user  staff   256 Aug  3 15:24 system-images/
drwxr-xr-x  14 user  staff   448 Oct  9  2017 tools/
```

Questions:

1. Where are the ***fonts*** and ***skins*** folder coming from?
2. Is there a way to download them from an URL?
3. Is there any **avdmanager** command to force it to be installed?

Here is my python script to automate the installation:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import urllib


# Android resource file
androidrc = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], '.androidrc')
if not os.path.exists(androidrc):
    with open(androidrc, 'w'):
        pass
# Bash resource file (~/.bashrc)
bashrc = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], '.bashrc')
# Environment variables needed for android
environment_variables = [
    ('ANDROID_TEMP_DIR', '/tmp/android'),
    ('ANDROID_HOME', '$HOME/Library/Android/sdk'),
    ('ANDROID_SDK_HOME', '$HOME'),
    ('ANDROID_TOOLS', '$ANDROID_HOME/tools'),
    ('ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS', '$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools')]


def humansize(nbytes):
    suffixes = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB']
    i = 0
    while nbytes >= 1024 and i < len(suffixes) - 1:
        nbytes /= 1024.
        i += 1
    f = ('%.2f' % nbytes).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
    return '%s %s' % (f, suffixes[i])


def add_to_bashrc():
    with open(bashrc, 'r') as bashrc_r:
        if androidrc not in bashrc_r.read():
            print("Including %s to %s" % (androidrc, bashrc))
            with open(bashrc, 'a') as bashrc_a:
                bashrc_a.write('''
# Adding environment for android
# include %s if it exists
if [ -f "%s" ]; then
    . "%s"
fi
''' % (androidrc, androidrc, androidrc))


def set_environment_variables():
    print("Creating/updating the %s resource file" % androidrc)
    with open(androidrc, 'w') as new_file:
        value = '''
# Setting environment for android
%s

export PATH=$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$ANDROID_TOOLS:$ANDROID_TOOLS/bin:$PATH
''' % '\n'.join(["export %s=%s" % (env[0], env[1]) for env in environment_variables])
        new_file.write(value)
    # Show content
    os.system('cat %s' % androidrc)


def install_android_sdk_tools():
    android_temp_dir = os.environ['ANDROID_TEMP_DIR']
    zip_file = os.path.join(android_temp_dir, "sdk-tools.zip")
    # Create android temp dir if doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(android_temp_dir):
        os.makedirs(android_temp_dir)
    if not os.path.exists(zip_file):
        # Download SDK tools zip file
        url = "https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-darwin-4333796.zip"
        print("Downloading sdk tools from: \n\t%s" % url)
        f = urllib.urlopen(url)
        with open(zip_file, "wb") as zipFile:
            zipFile.write(f.read())
        print("SDK tools downloaded to: \n\t%s [%s]" % (zip_file, humansize(os.path.getsize(zip_file))))
    # create android home if doesn't exists
    android_home = os.environ['ANDROID_HOME']
    if not os.path.exists(android_home):
        os.makedirs(android_home)
    # unzip SDK tools zip file into android home
    os.system('unzip -o %s -d %s' % (zip_file, android_home))
    print("\n%s content:\n" % android_home)
    os.system('ls -la %s' % android_home)

def install_android_platform_tools():
    print("\nInstalling 'platform-tools'...\n")
    os.system('echo "y\n" | sdkmanager "platform-tools"')


def install_android_platforms():
    print("\nInstalling platforms 23 to 28...\n")
    for i in range(23, 28):
        print("\nInstalling platforms;android-%s" % i)
        os.system('sdkmanager "platforms;android-%s"' % i)


def install_android_system_images():
    print("Installing system images 23 to 28...\n")
    for i in range(23, 28):
        print("\nInstalling system-images;android-%s;google_apis;x86" % i)
        os.system('echo "y\n" | sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-%s;google_apis;x86"' % i)


def install_emulator_skins():
    print("\nInstalling emulator...\n")
    os.system('sdkmanager "emulator"')
    print("\nInstalling skins...\n")
    android_temp_dir = os.environ['ANDROID_TEMP_DIR']
    # For now, I am downloading a pre-zipped file from storage URL
    # This is not the desired behavior, but is working for now
    skins_url = "https://www.example.com/skins.zip"
    print("Downloading skins from: \n\t%s" % skins_url)
    f = urllib.urlopen(skins_url)
    zip_file = os.path.join(android_temp_dir, "skins.zip")
    with open(zip_file, "wb") as zipFile:
        zipFile.write(f.read())
    print("Skins downloaded to: \n\t%s [%s]" % (zip_file, humansize(os.path.getsize(zip_file))))
    android_home = os.environ['ANDROID_HOME']
    # unzip skin zip file into android home
    os.system('unzip -o %s -d %s' % (zip_file, android_home))


def accept_licenses():
    print("\nAccepting all licenses...\n")
    os.system('echo "yes\n" | sdkmanager --licenses')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # 1. Set environment variables
    set_environment_variables()
    add_to_bashrc()
    # 2. Install SDK tools
    install_android_sdk_tools()
    # 3. Install platform-tools
    install_android_platform_tools()
    # 4. Install android platforms
    install_android_platforms()
    # 5. Install system images
    install_android_system_images()
    # 6. Install skins
    install_emulator_skins() # <- This is where I need help
    # 7. Accept all licenses
    accept_licenses()
```

How do I get the skins from Google's repository?